# WCF REST Authetication

Tags: c#, android, wcf, rest, authentication

I have implemented OAuth Authentication for the WCF REST Service (c#) which is responding in JSON Format by using link http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/817102/Consuming-OAUTH-Enabled-Restful-WCF-Service-using this authentication is working fine  but client is saying that "we dont use js... mobile native client is Objective-c for iOS and Java for android.." Could you please suggest which is the best way to implement Authentication in this scenario. I read many article but most of them are using certificates for Authentication. Could you please advise any basic authentication like just passing username and password or any inbuilt authentication...

Comment: What's the problem? You've implemented an Oauth Service, and have example consuming code in JS. But you could also have made example code in C#, Java etc.OAuth in a language agnostic protocol, the client needs to write some code (or you need to write an iOS/Java SDK in addition to your js code)

Comment: Is there any example code online to show client how to consume Oauth Service from Objective-c & Java.. I can't find any examples online   Or just give some idea or example code how to consume it from client side. @NathanCooper

Comment: The facebook graph api uses OAuth, so that's a thing to look into. I had a quick look and found an [IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/se-oauthjavapt3/index.html) tutorial in java, may be related.

Answer (score 0):

It should not be too hard to find information about this. A quick Google search turned up [this Google Developers page](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2#overview), for example. I haven't drilled too much into the details, but it seems reliable and relevant to what your asking for.

From the summary:

> This document explains how to use the GoogleCredential utility class to do OAuth 2.0 authorization with Google services. For information about the generic OAuth 2.0 functions that we provide, see OAuth 2.0 and the Google OAuth Client Library for Java.

They also provide a link to Google`s OAuth API:

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/oauth2/package-summary